# How do I achieve addition of each rows in T-SQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have my data which may be around 50 records for each address:

```
Id  AddressId   Income  Expense Revenue
----------------------------------------
1   1           100     200     300
2   1           150      20     200
3   1           160      80     800
4   1            50      90     200
5   1           600     700     500
```

Now  I need my data in the following format:

```
Ids       Count Income  Expense Revenue
---------------------------------------
1           1    100     200     300
1,2         2    250     220     500
1,2,3       3    410     300    1300
1,2,3,4     4    460     390    1500
1,2,3,4,5   5   1060    1090    2000
```

Every row is being added one after another.

For example:

- The `Ids 1,2` is a sum of Id 1 and 2
- The `Ids 1,2,3` is a sum of Id 1 and 2 and 3 and so on

I don't need the Ids column, the only thing I need is the sum

Comment: This sounds like something that would be trivial to do in the code that consumes the data, and awkward to do in TSQL

Comment: @MarcGravell actually quite easy to do with TSql, as long as you are not working an a really old version, using the `over` clause with `sum` and the propert `partition by` and `order by` makes it a walk in the park...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `STUFF`, `ROW_NUMBER() OVER()`, and `SUM() OVER()` like this

```
DECLARE @SampleData AS TABLE
(
    Id int, 
    AddressId int,
    Income int,
    Expense int,
    Revenue int
)

INSERT INTO @SampleData
VALUES
( 1, 1, 100, 200, 300),
( 2, 1, 150, 20 , 200),
( 3, 1, 160, 80 , 800),
( 4, 1, 50 , 90 , 200),
( 5, 1, 600, 700, 500)

SELECT 
      STUFF(
             (
             SELECT ',' + CAST(sd1.Id AS varchar(10))
             FROM @SampleData sd1
             WHERE sd1.AddressId = sd.AddressId AND sd1.Id <= sd.Id
             FOR XML PATH('')
             ), 
          1,1,'') AS Ids,
      Row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY sd.AddressId ORDER BY sd.Id) AS Count,
      sum(sd.Income)  OVER(PARTITION BY sd.AddressId ORDER BY sd.Id) AS Income,
      sum(sd.Expense)  OVER(PARTITION BY sd.AddressId ORDER BY sd.Id) AS Expense,
      sum(sd.Revenue)  OVER(PARTITION BY sd.AddressId ORDER BY sd.Id) AS Revenue
FROM @SampleData sd
ORDER BY sd.AddressId, sd.Id
```

Demo link: http://rextester.com/HRIWH92029

Note: The last revenue should be 2000 instead of 1600

Answer (score 1):

If you're using SQL server 2012 and above,
please use below query for the sum up the previous rows

```
Select ID, 
count(*) OVER (PARTITION by AddressID
ORDER BY ID
ROWS BETWEEN unbounded PRECEDING AND current row) as[Count],
sum(Income) OVER (PARTITION by AddressID
ORDER BY ID
ROWS BETWEEN unbounded PRECEDING AND current row) Income,
sum(Expense) OVER (PARTITION by AddressID
ORDER BY ID
ROWS BETWEEN unbounded PRECEDING AND current row)Expense,
sum(Revenue) OVER (PARTITION by AddressID
ORDER BY ID
ROWS BETWEEN unbounded PRECEDING AND current row) Revenue from TableName
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using SQL server 2008 and below, please use below query for the sum up the previous rows.

```
Select ID, (select count(*) from Tablename A where A.Id<=Tablename.ID)[Count], 
(select sum(Income) from Tablename A where A.Id<=Tablename.ID) Income, (select 
sum(Expense) from Tablename A where A.Id<=Tablename.ID) Expense, (select 
sum(Revenue) from Tablename A where A.Id<=Tablename.ID) Revenue from Tablename
```